# Flushing right an equation in flalign, moves it outside the page margin

Tags: equations, formatting, amsmath

I want to shift one equation to extreme right within align or flalign, but it moves outside the page margin. MWE is given below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1] \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \begin{flalign*}
    x&=(a+b^2)(a+c^2+ sqrt(a+b^2))(a+b^2)(a+c^2+ sqrt(a+b^2))\\
    &=z(a+c^2 +sqrt(z)) z(a+c^2 +sqrt(z))\\
&&where \ \ z=(a+b^2)
%   \sin 2x &= 2\sin x\cos x \\ 
%   &&\cos 2x &= \cos^2 x-\sin^2 x
    \end{flalign*}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: surely you don't want `sqrt` and `where` set in math italic here.

Comment: yes that is also needed. But keeping it in the margin is prime concern to me.

Comment: why is the where... text in the alignment at all, just put it after the alignment flush right if you want it flush right

Comment: Actually there are some other equations after ---where--- statement and I had tried flush right within flalign it did not work.

Comment: you can use `\intertext` to add text within the align, or just use a second alignment.

Comment: I am not a mathematician and hence don't use `flaglin`-environments.  But shouldn't it have only one `&`?  I think, the `&&` is one to much?

Comment: @Jan: No, `flalign`, like `align`, can be used with multiple alignment points.

Comment: @David O.K. got it using \intertext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d do this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1] \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \begingroup
        \setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}
        \begin{multline*}
            x=(a+b^2)(a+c^2+\sqrt(a+b^2))(a+b^2)(a+c^2+\sqrt(a+b^2))\\
            =z(a+c^2+\sqrt(z)) z(a+c^2+\sqrt(z))\\
            \text{where } z=(a+b^2)
        \end{multline*}
    \endgroup
    \lipsum[2]
    And another use of \texttt{multline*}:
    \begin{multline*}
        a=\\b=\\c
    \end{multline*}
    As you can see, \verb|\multilinegap| has again the default value.
\end{document}
```

Here’s the output:

[image: Output of the above code]

**Addition:**  If you insist on getting the first two rows aligned at the `=` sign, the following is perhaps the most straightforward solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1] \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \begingroup
        \setlength{\multlinegap}{0pt}
        \begin{multline*}
            \begin{aligned}
                x&=(a+b^2)(a+c^2+\sqrt(a+b^2))(a+b^2)(a+c^2+\sqrt(a+b^2))\\
                &=z(a+c^2+\sqrt(z)) z(a+c^2+\sqrt(z))
            \end{aligned} \\
            \text{where } z=(a+b^2)
        \end{multline*}
    \endgroup
    \lipsum[2]
    And another use of \texttt{multline*}:
    \begin{multline*}
        a=\\b=\\c
    \end{multline*}
    As you can see, \verb|\multilinegap| has again the default value.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the second code sample]

**Second addition:** And don’t forget that there is also the magic `\hidewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1] \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \begin{flalign*}
        x&=(a+b^2)(a+c^2+\sqrt(a+b^2))(a+b^2)(a+c^2+\sqrt(a+b^2))\\
        &=z(a+c^2+\sqrt(z)) z(a+c^2+\sqrt(z))\\
        &&\hidewidth \text{where } z=a+b^2
    \end{flalign*}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the third code sample]

Comment: Tried Second Addition. It is wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

the `where...` is part of the sentence structure, not mathematics and doesn't need to align so just place it outside the alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1] \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \begin{flalign*}
    x&=(a+b^2)(a+c^2+ \sqrt{a+b^2})(a+b^2)(a+c^2+ \sqrt{a+b^2})\\
    &=z(a+c^2 +\sqrt{z}) z(a+c^2 +\sqrt{z})
\end{flalign*}
\begin{flushright}
where $z=(a+b^2)$
\end{flushright}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`flalign` works fine in cooperation with `\mathllap`(from `mathtools`). I propose a second solution, with `alignat` (and, again,`\mathllap):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}%
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1]
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
    \begin{flalign*}
& & x&=(a+b^2)(a+c^2+\sqrt{a+b^2})(a+b^2)(a+c^2+ \sqrt{a+b^2}) & & \\
   & & &=z(a+c^2 +\sqrt{z}) z(a+c^2 + \sqrt{z})\\
 & & &&& \mathllap{\text{where\enspace}z=a+b^2}
    \end{flalign*}
    \lipsum[2]
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
 x&=(a+b^2)(a+c^2+\sqrt{a+b^2})(a+b^2) & (a+c^2+ \sqrt{a+b^2}) & \\
   &=z(a+c^2 +\sqrt{z}) z(a+c^2 + \sqrt{z})\\
   &&& \mathllap{\text{where\enspace}z=a+b^2}
    \end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]